# probability in rock paper and scissors

Tags: probability

This is actually a programming Question I had faced 2 times.
Q) Mark was left behind on Mars by his crew. He found species there similar to humans.He taught them the game of Rock-Paper-Scissor (one item destroys other). You are given count of number of rocks,scissors and papers on that planet.Your task is to find for each item the probability of their survival on that planet after a long period of time.
 
My solution was something like this lets suppose there are R rocks ,P papers and S scissors.

## P(Rock last)=P(select 1 or more rocks from total)*P(Scissor dies first)

but I am unable to compute P(scissor dies first)

Comment: Your question is phrased in an extremely obscure manner. What do you mean by "You are given count of number of rocks,scissors and papers on that planet"? It sounds like each "person" plays with the same item (rock, paper or scissors) every time. How is the game played? Are they divided into $N$ couples, and the winner from each couple continues to the next level?

Comment: According to me the question is like 
suppose you have R rocks P papers and S scissors
now any 2 of them can play against each other at random suppose in first match Rock plays against scissor now number of rocks after 1st round will remain R but number of scissors will reduce to S-1.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the respective probabilities of Rock being the only survivor in the game , Scissor being the only survivor in the game and Paper being the only survivor in the game.

Comment: The first two paragraphs of your answer do not answer anything. The OP probably knows what rock-paper-scissors is.